# While Controller after completing isn't executing next thread

Tags: jmeter

I have a Thread group which takes data from CSV,in CSV i have few rows of data and first column of CSV file is defined as counter. I am having while loop controller in thread once the loop is completed successfully i.e. looped through all the data, its not executing next thread group in test plan.

In CSV Data Set Config:
i have set Recycle on EOF : False
Stop thread on EOF : True

Once loop is completed, should move on to next Thread Group.
[image]

While Loop Condition Variable.
[image]

Submit Order: Thread Group isn't getting executed
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To continue Thread, you should set `Stop thread on EOF` to `False`

and check in While controller you didn't reached EOF:

`"${Count}" != "<EOF>"`